# Exception handling with @ControllerAdvice on spring Rest

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controllerAdvice class as below for handling two exception

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyGlobalExceptionHandler{
    @ExceptionHandler({ UserNotFoundException.class, ContentNotAllowedException.class }){

//my code here 

}
```

Now on controller if I put my code inside `try catch` block, will those two `exception` ever reach controllerAdvice class ?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<?>  getMyUrl(@Valid @ModelAttribute MyObject ap,BindingResult bindingResult ) {    
try{    
     //my code here that will throw  UserNotFoundException or ContentNotAllowedException
}Catch(Exception e){
    //handle exception here    
}
```

I could not understand how exception handling will occur in above example.

Comment: No, since no exception is ever thrown from your controller method: you're catching them all. Why don't you just test it?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: The comment if now correct, but the situation is identical: a controller advice can handle exceptions thrown by controllers. If the controller doesn't throw anything, there is no exception to handle.

Comment: its simple - **you** handled the exception in `catch`. Nothing to catch by **uncounght** exceptions handler.

Comment: that means i have to throw exception on catch block so they will reach to controller advice ?

Comment: @user9735824 **yes**...or just **do not use `try` `catch`**, and just declare that your method throws some exception like this: `getMyUrl(/*params omitted*/) throws  UserNotFoundException, ContentNotAllowedException {`

Comment: If i am handling 10 different exceptions, i need to put all exception on method after throws.... ?

Comment: @user9735824 yup, only the ones that can occur in that method, of course

Comment: I think you don't really nderstand the principle of exceptions in the first place. read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?>  getMyUrl(@Valid @ModelAttribute MyObject ap,BindingResult bindingResult ) {    
    try{    
        // Your code here that will throw  UserNotFoundException or ContentNotAllowedException
    } catch(Exception exception){

        if (exception instanceof UserNotFoundException || exception instanceof ContentNotAllowedException) {
             throw exception;
        }

        // Handle other types of exceptions here    
    }
}
```

and then only `UserNotFoundException` and `ContentNotAllowedException` will not be handled and your `@ExceptionHandler` method in your `@ControllerAdvice` will be able to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

@ControllerAdvice is used to intercept exceptions from controllers. It is used when an application has more than one controller and specific exception needs to be intercepted or handled in unique way. The exception handling in the controller depends on how you construct the ResponseEntity in MyGlobalExceptionHandler.